# Texworks does not update bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texworks, update

I can perfectly compile `main.tex` file below and have a pdf on OverLeaf but can't do it on TeXworks on my pc. So I can't have reference section.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}


\title{Life is too short to learn LaTeX}    % Title
\author{Rageful}    % Author
\date{01.01.2019} % Date

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\cfoot{\thepage}


\renewcommand{\refname}{Referance}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
   \centering
\vspace*{0.5 cm}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.08]{latex.png}\\[1.0 cm] 
{\centering \textsc{\LARGE \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ LATEX} \newline\newline \textsc{\LARGE PROJECT}\\[2.0 cm]} 
\textsc{\Large 17.01.2019}\\[0.5 cm]    
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]
{ \huge \bfseries \thetitle}\\
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[3.5 cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{Person A}\\
        \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}~
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}

        \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{Person B :} \\
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2 cm]
\end{titlepage}

\section{Preface}

Why is LaTeX too hard? \cite{Human:1}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\water} % bibliography prints here

\end{document}
```

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255038/how-to-use-bib-file-in-my-own-latex-file/255042) post is too complicated to understand. It doesn't work.

Here is `water.bib` file:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\water.bib}
@BOOK{Human:1,
  title = {{R}ocket {P}ropulsion {E}lements},
  publisher = {John Wiley Sons},
  author = Name J.~E.},
  year = {2017},
  edition = {4th},
}

@ARTICLE{Person:2,
  author = {Jones, A.~B. and Smith, J.~M.},
  title = {{A}rticle {T}itle},
  journal = {{J}ournal {T}itle},
  year = {2013},
  volume = {13},
  pages = {123-456},
  number = {52},
  month = {March},
  publisher = {Publisher}
  }
\end{filecontents}
```

**EDIT:** This is the error:

```
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./main.out) (./main.out)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1{c:/texlive    /2018/texm
f-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./images/latex.png>]
Runaway argument?
]{NAME:1} 
! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.74
```

?

Comment: Is `\begin{filecontents}{\water.bib}` correct? Should it be `\begin{filecontents}{water.bib}`?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure about the claim that "I can perfectly compile main.tex file below ... on OverLeaf"? To get your code to compile, I had to (a) change both instances of `\water` to `water`, (b) not load the `natbib` package (since it's a mistake to load both `natbib` and `cite`),  (c) in the entry `Human:1`, change `author = Name J.~E.}` to `author = {Name J.~E.}` (can you spot the missing `{` symbol?), and (d) used `\cite` commands to cite either `Human:1` or `Person:2`. Your code currently features `\cite{NAME:1}`, but you do not provide an entry with key `NAME:1`...

Comment: I changed \cite{NAME:1} to \cite{Human:1}. But I still can't see referance section.

Comment: After making the four changes given above, did you perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX)?

Comment: I performed but somehow this is too confusing: 1) Should I include bibtex code in tex file? I hope I shouldn't. 2) First pdflatex command gives error (Package natbib Warning: Citation `BOOK:1' on page 3 undefined on input line 2).

Comment: Finally I have done. The last error I fixed is: \bibliography{\bibfilename} > \bibliography{bibfilename}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed here two things.

First: The part

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} % <===========================================
@BOOK{Human:1,
  title = {{R}ocket {P}ropulsion {E}lements},
  publisher = {John Wiley Sons},
  author = Name J.~E.},
  year = {2017},
  edition = {4th},
}

@ARTICLE{Person:2,
  author = {Jones, A.~B. and Smith, J.~M.},
  title = {{A}rticle {T}itle},
  journal = {{J}ournal {T}itle},
  year = {2013},
  volume = {13},
  pages = {123-456},
  number = {52},
  month = {March},
  publisher = {Publisher}
  }
\end{filecontents}
```

is only used to build an compilable MWE including TeX code and `bib` file. Suppose you have the file `mwe.tex` then `\jobname.bib` is changed to `mwe.bib` to be accessable from the MWE.

Usually you have a file `mybib.bib` you can address to you code (if it is in the same directory) with `\bibliography{mybib}` Please see that the extention `.bib` is ommitted.

So in your case simply use

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Human:1,
  title = {{R}ocket {P}ropulsion {E}lements},
  publisher = {John Wiley Sons},
  author = Name J.~E.},
  year = {2017},
  edition = {4th},
}

@ARTICLE{Person:2,
  author = {Jones, A.~B. and Smith, J.~M.},
  title = {{A}rticle {T}itle},
  journal = {{J}ournal {T}itle},
  year = {2013},
  volume = {13},
  pages = {123-456},
  number = {52},
  month = {March},
  publisher = {Publisher}
  }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % <===============================================


\title{Life is too short to learn LaTeX}    % Title
\author{Rageful}    % Author
\date{01.01.2019} % Date

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\cfoot{\thepage}


\renewcommand{\refname}{Referance}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
   \centering
\vspace*{0.5 cm}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.08]{latex.png}\\[1.0 cm] 
{\centering \textsc{\LARGE \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ LATEX} \newline\newline \textsc{\LARGE PROJECT}\\[2.0 cm]} 
\textsc{\Large 17.01.2019}\\[0.5 cm]    
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]
{ \huge \bfseries \thetitle}\\
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[3.5 cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{Person A}\\
        \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}~
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}

        \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{Person B :} \\
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2 cm]
\end{titlepage}

\section{Preface}

Why is LaTeX too hard? \cite{NAME:1}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname} % bibliography prints here

\end{document}
```

to show your issue with an MWE.

SECOND: in real simply use

file `mybib.bib`

```
@BOOK{Human:1,
  title = {{R}ocket {P}ropulsion {E}lements},
  publisher = {John Wiley Sons},
  author = Name J.~E.},
  year = {2017},
  edition = {4th},
}

@ARTICLE{Person:2,
  author = {Jones, A.~B. and Smith, J.~M.},
  title = {{A}rticle {T}itle},
  journal = {{J}ournal {T}itle},
  year = {2013},
  volume = {13},
  pages = {123-456},
  number = {52},
  month = {March},
  publisher = {Publisher}
  }
```

and the productive tex code, for example `test.tex`  (see command `\bibliography{mybib}` at the end):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % <===============================================


\title{Life is too short to learn LaTeX}    % Title
\author{Rageful}    % Author
\date{01.01.2019} % Date

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\cfoot{\thepage}


\renewcommand{\refname}{Referance}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
   \centering
\vspace*{0.5 cm}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.08]{latex.png}\\[1.0 cm] 
{\centering \textsc{\LARGE \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ LATEX} \newline\newline \textsc{\LARGE PROJECT}\\[2.0 cm]} 
\textsc{\Large 17.01.2019}\\[0.5 cm]    
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]
{ \huge \bfseries \thetitle}\\
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[3.5 cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{Person A}\\
        \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}~
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}

        \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{Person B :} \\
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2 cm]
\end{titlepage}

\section{Preface}

Why is LaTeX too hard? \cite{NAME:1}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybib} % bibliography prints here <====================

\end{document}
```

Please see that I changed the order of calling `hyperref`: in your case is should be called last and do not call packages twice (I deleted the second call of `hyperref` in the code above) ...

## UPDATE:

Now let us have a look on your given code. There are some issues too:

- You called package `cite` causing the error you mentioned. Please read the documentation of `cite` with typing `texdoc cite` on your terminal/console. If you want to use package `cite`, you need to delete the call of `natbib` (you can not use both together) and use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`.
- If you want to use `natbib` (please read documentation with `texdoc natbib` on your console/terminal) you need to delete the call of `cite` and to change the used bibliography style to `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`. To get numbered bib entries add option `numbers` to `natbib`: `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`. For the following MWE I choosed this variant ...
- In your bib entry  `Human:1` is a `{` missing for author:

  ```
  @BOOK{Human:1,
    title = {{R}ocket {P}ropulsion {E}lements},
    publisher = {John Wiley Sons},
    author = {Name J.~E.},
    year = {2017},
    edition = {4th},
  }
  ```
- In your bib file is no bib entry `NAME:1` you call in your tex code. I changed it to `Human:1`.

Now please see the following compilable code

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Human:1,
  title = {{R}ocket {P}ropulsion {E}lements},
  publisher = {John Wiley Sons},
  author = {Name J.~E.},
  year = {2017},
  edition = {4th},
}

@ARTICLE{Person:2,
  author = {Jones, A.~B. and Smith, J.~M.},
  title = {{A}rticle {T}itle},
  journal = {{J}ournal {T}itle},
  year = {2013},
  volume = {13},
  pages = {123--456},
  number = {52},
  month = {March},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % <===================================
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{pgfplots} % <========================= not needed for issue
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % <===============================================


\title{Life is too short to learn LaTeX}    % Title
\author{Rageful}    % Author
\date{01.01.2019} % Date

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\cfoot{\thepage}


\renewcommand{\refname}{Referance}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
   \centering
\vspace*{0.5 cm}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.08]{example-image}\\[1.0 cm] 
{\centering \textsc{\LARGE \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ LATEX} \newline\newline \textsc{\LARGE PROJECT}\\[2.0 cm]} 
\textsc{\Large 17.01.2019}\\[0.5 cm]    
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]
{ \huge \bfseries \thetitle}\\
\rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[3.5 cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{Person A}\\
        \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}~
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}

        \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{Person B :} \\
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2 cm]
\end{titlepage}

\section{Preface}

Why is LaTeX too hard? \cite{Human:1}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % <==================================
\bibliography{\jobname} % bibliography prints here

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image]

At last a remark: your used `\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \` to build your title page is wrong. Better use `\vspace{3cm}` and change the used value for your needs ...

Comment: I left comments below the query, rather than provide a standalone answer, as I believed that the OP's code was so full of errors that the OP's claim, that TeXworks was somehow to blame, had to be challenged directly...

Answer (score 0):

You need to run

latex
bibtex
latex 
latex

Overleaf does that for you. In Texworks, you need to do it manually. Next to the green button you use to compile, you can choose what you want to run :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you verify that your suggestions lead to success, using the OP's code as the starting point?

Comment: I only just saw the edit. I misunderstood. Sorry!